# Syncing React-Select Async List with Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-select

So for the most part I managed to get multi async select working for react-select.

The following in a block of code:

```
const targeted = metadata[item.label];
<AsyncSelect
  loadOptions={this.getOptions.bind(this, item.label)}
  value={targeted.value}
  data={targeted}
/>
```

So the above is just a quick snippet of my AsyncSelect. `metadata` is a mapToProp defined and pulled from my redux state for the block of code above that is in one component. The scenario here is that I removed the value from an external function outside of this component - everywhere else updates when that associated metadata prop is altered, but multi async select value does not remove - I have to physically click the "x" next to each value input in the multi async input.

[image: Example of my multi async select]

Thanks for the help in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Ok - I have no idea it took in an array for the value - d'oh - so disregard!